# i want to select certain column and create new column which ll return column name if true in pyhton?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame

```
A     AA   B       D     C       E
True   2   False   33    False   False
False  3   False   43    True    False
True   5   True   56    False    True
False  2   False   7     nan     True
```

I want to get column named "result" which will return the columns name from A,B and C if it is true and nan, if any of it is not True.

Expected Column

```
result
A
C
A,B  
nan
```

Answer (score 1):

First compare values by `True`s, then add matrix multiplication with columns with separator by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html), remove separator from right side by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and last replace empty values to missing values:

```
df['result'] = df.eq(True).dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').replace('',np.nan)
print (df)
       A  AA      B   D      C result
0   True   2  False  33  False      A
1  False   3  False  43   True      C
2   True   5   True  56  False    A,B
3  False   2  False   7    NaN    NaN
```